# JsonParseException while importing JSON to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to import some json data into my elasticsearch instance and getting the following error:

```
{
  "error" : "JsonParseException[Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for ARRAY (from [Source: [B@7110db07; line: 1, column: 0])\n at [Source: [B@7110db07; line: 1, column: 3]]",
  "status" : 500
}
```

I am using an Ubuntu (14.04) running on VirtualBox and this is the command I used to import the data:

```
url -XPOST 'localhost:9200/mydata/fields/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary @mydata.json
```

And here is my JSON sample:

```
[
  {
    "field1":"sometext",
    "field2":"O",
    "field3":"TEXT",
    "field4":"CR",
    "field5":"09:38.0",
    "field6":"09:38.0",
    "field7":"14:13.0",
    "field8":"NULL",
    "field9":"NULL",
    "field10":"0",
    "field11":"5",
    "field12":"NULL",
    "field13":"NULL",
    "field14":"4",
    "field15":"0"
  },
  {
    "field1":"othertext",
    "field2":"O",
    "field3":"TEXT",
    "field4":"CR",
    "field5":"09:38.0",
    "field6":"09:38.0",
    "field7":"14:13.0",
    "field8":"NULL",
    "field9":"NULL",
    "field10":"0",
    "field11":"5",
    "field12":"NULL",
    "field13":"NULL",
    "field14":"4",
    "field15":"0"
  },
]
```

Is is possible to import a JSON array using the bulk API?

Comment: Corrected json format is like so:  
  
`{"index":{"_index":"mydata","_type":"data","_id":0}}  
{"field1":"someText","field2":"O","field3":"TEXT","field4":"CR","field5":"09:38.0","field6":"09:38.0","field7":"14:13.0","field8":"NULL","field9":"NULL","field10":"0","field11":"5","field12":"NULL","field13":"NULL","field14":"4","field15":"0"}`

Comment: what about the second record?

Comment: how did you post multiple records using bulk api? i always get an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your json doesnt have to contain line breaks in the bulk API, since the API uses the line break as a delimiter. From elasticsearch documentation here http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html

> Because this format uses literal \n's as delimiters, please be sure
>   that the JSON actions and sources are not pretty printed.